# Adding a function to a string split command in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has 20 or so columns in it. One of the columns is called 'director_name' and has values such as 'John Doe' or 'Jane Doe'.  I want to split this into 2 columns, 'First_Name' and 'Last_Name'.  When I run the following it works as expected and splits the string into 2 columns:

```
data[['First_Name', 'Last_Name']] = data.director_name.str.split(' ', expand 
= True) 
data

First_Name    Last_Name
John          Doe
```

It works great, however it does NOT work when I have NULL (NaN) values under 'director_name'.  It throws the following error:

```
'Columns must be same length as key'
```

I'd like to add a function which checks if the value != null, then do the command listed above, otherwise enter 'NA' for First_Name and 'Last_Name'

Any ideas how I would go about that?

EDIT:

I just checked the file and I'm not sure if NULL is the issue.  I have some names that are 3-4 strings long.  i.e.

```
John Allen Doe
John Allen Doe Jr
```

Maybe I can't split this into First_Name and Last_Name.

Hmmmm

Comment: This works for me.  What version of pandas/python are you using?

Comment: Python 3, Pandas 0.20.1.  It works when you have null values?  I thought that was why the error was showing for me. Maybe its some other reason?  File has 5k records, when I do .head(10) and all values are there it works, when i open it up to the whole file (that has NULL values in 'director_name') it doesnt

Comment: The error is because some of the fields would have more than one space, I had updated the answer to your previous question to handle that

Comment: @JD2775, I have also tried it, and it works properly.

Comment: If there is a value say 'Robert Downey Jr', this code will throw and error as it expects exactly two fields, solution is split and take first two values.df['First_Name'] = df.name.str.split(' ', expand = True)[0]
df['Last_Name'] = df.name.str.split(' ', expand = True)[1]

Comment: Thank you A-Z. that appears to be the issue (I just edited my OP). Not sure I can feasibly split this into 2 columns.  Would be curious to know how to split it into n Columns though.  i.e  Name_1, Name_2.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way is to split and choose say the first two values as first name and last name

```
    Id  name
0   1   James Cameron
1   2   Martin Sheen
2   3   John Allen Doe
3   4   NaN


df['First_Name'] = df.name.str.split(' ', expand = True)[0]
df['Last_Name'] = df.name.str.split(' ', expand = True)[1]
```

You get

```
    Id  name            First_Name  Last_Name
0   1   James Cameron   James       Cameron
1   2   Martin Sheen    Martin      Sheen
2   3   John Allen Doe  John        Allen
3   4   NaN             NaN         None
```

Comment: That's perfect.  Thanks A-Z

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) (no parameter, because splitter by default whitespace) with [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) for select lists by position:

```
print (df.name.str.split())
0      [James, Cameron]
1       [Martin, Sheen]
2    [John, Allen, Doe]
3                   NaN
Name: name, dtype: object

df['First_Name'] = df.name.str.split().str[0]
df['Last_Name'] = df.name.str.split().str[1]

#data borrow from A-Za-z answer
print (df)
   Id            name First_Name Last_Name
0   1   James Cameron      James   Cameron
1   2    Martin Sheen     Martin     Sheen
2   3  John Allen Doe       John     Allen
3   4             NaN        NaN       NaN
```

There is also possible use paramter `n` for selecting second or first 2 names:

```
df['First_Name'] = df.name.str.split().str[0]
df['Last_Name'] = df.name.str.split(n=1).str[1]
print (df)
   Id            name First_Name  Last_Name
0   1   James Cameron      James    Cameron
1   2    Martin Sheen     Martin      Sheen
2   3  John Allen Doe       John  Allen Doe
3   4             NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Solution with [`str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html)

```
df['First_Name'] = df.name.str.rsplit(n=1).str[0]
df['Last_Name'] = df.name.str.rsplit().str[-1]
print (df)
   Id            name  First_Name Last_Name
0   1   James Cameron       James   Cameron
1   2    Martin Sheen      Martin     Sheen
2   3  John Allen Doe  John Allen       Doe
3   4             NaN         NaN       NaN
```

Comment: There is simple rule - if use standard pandas functions, there works nice with `NaN`s ;) Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This should fix your problem

**Setup**

```
data= pd.DataFrame({'director_name': {0: 'John Doe', 1: np.nan, 2: 'Alan Smith'}})

data
Out[457]: 
  director_name
0      John Doe
1           NaN
2    Alan Smith
```

**Solution**

```
#use a lambda function to check nan before splitting the column.
data[['First_Name', 'Last_Name']] = data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([np.nan,np.nan] if pd.isnull(x.director_name) else x.director_name.split()), axis=1)

data
Out[446]: 
  director_name First_Name Last_Name
0      John Doe       John       Doe
1           NaN        NaN       NaN
2    Alan Smith       Alan     Smith
```

If you need to take only the first 2 names, you can do:

```
data[['First_Name', 'Last_Name']] = data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([np.nan,np.nan] if pd.isnull(x.director_name) else x.director_name.split()).iloc[:2], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Allen!  Making note of all these solutions for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

```
df['First_Name'] = df.name.str.split(' ', expand = True)[0]
df['Last_Name'] = df.name.str.split(' ', expand = True)[1]
```

This should do